# Sprite css menu - cannot align large logo in div over menu

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

I have been fighting with this issue for several days now. I have a sprite menu that works as expected with all my hover events, however I want to put the complete logo over the top of my "center" element.  When I am in Dreamweaver it displays as expected, however when I use Safari or Chrome the logo from the "logo" element is misplaced. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="logo">
<h1 class="logo">
<a href="#" title="Test">Logo</a>
</h1>
</div>
<ul>
 <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a class="products" href="#">Products</a></li>
 <li><a class="philosophy" href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
 <li><a class="center" href="#">Center</a></li>
 <li><a class="news" href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a class="myaccount" href="#">My Account</a></li>
 <li><a class="customercare" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>​
```

Here is the CSS for one of the menu elements as well as the CSS for the center image.

```
ul {
width: 1000px;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li {
float: left;    
}

ul li a {
height: 50px;
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

/*home*/
ul li a.home {
background-image: url('sprites.optimized.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 0px;
width: 100px;
}

ul li a.home:hover {
background-image: url('sprites.optimized.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -50px;
}
/*Main Logo*/
#logo {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}

#logo h1 {
/* [disabled]height: 100px; */
/* [disabled]width: 201px; */
margin: -100px 282px;
/* [disabled]padding: 0; */
}

#logo h1 a {
color: transparent;
background: transparent url('CenterLogo.png') no-repeat;
width: 370px;
height: 201px;
top: 10px;
left: 30px;
margin: 0 0;
z-index: 200;
}

/***** Header Logo *****/
h1.logo a {
background: url('CenterLogo.png') no-repeat center right /* Company Logo */;
display: block;
height: 35px /* Sets overall height of header */;
margin: 0px 0 0 -2000px ;
outline: none /* Removes Link Outline */;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
top: 0px;
width: 2195px;
}​
```

Edit 1 -------
Per Tim I made the following changes

```
ul {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

I also changed the logo spacing and switched it to relative to see if I can get it in the right position.

```
/*Main Logo*/
#logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#logo h1 {
    /* [disabled]height: 100px; */
    /* [disabled]width: 201px; */
    margin: -100px 282px;
    /* [disabled]padding: 0; */
}
```

I can get it to display in the right position now, however when I scale my window the menu moves apart from the logo.

Edit 2 ------
Per Kraz I made the following change.  The menu now behaves as expected.

```
ul {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    /*margin-right: auto;*/
    /*margin-left: auto;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: First thing I notice: your `ul` and `li` don't have `display: block`, yet you use `float`

Comment: @TimVermaelen `ul` and `li` are both block elements by default.

Comment: you're also missing a `}` for ul li a.home:hover

Comment: @TimVermaelen I added it in, when I was formatting it for stackoverflow I deleted it by mistake.  Thanks for the catch :)

Comment: Jrod is right though, ul li are display block by default. Now from my xp you use display: inline-block for horizontal menus.

Now for the logo if you put position relative on the #logo and position absolute for the .logo the top, left, right, bottom attributes are available to position the .logo. The anchor css doesn't really matter then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however when I scale my window the menu moves apart from the logo.

Your logo is a relatively positioned block element. Your menu is also a relatively positionned block element.

Your logo simply appear where it has to appear. (top left corner)

However, your menu as a specific width (1000px) and it's right and left margin are set to `auto`. Hence **it is centered according to its container width**. And since it's probably the body, increasing the page width will move the menu to the right.